# ebpf: sending data from userspace and waiting for that

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, lsm, ebpf

I'm using ebpf and bcc to write an ebpf-lsm program. I want to block a connected USB device and send its info to userspace and the user send me whether I bind that device or no.

how can I do this? I know using ebpf maps we can receive data from userspace, well how can I wait for that? in another word, how can I block ebpf program until user responses?

thank you for any guidness!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with BPF today; you can't block the program's execution until some userspace process answers.

You may want to look at [`ptrace(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) and/or [seccomp-bpf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seccomp.2.html) instead. See for example [*Deferring seccomp decisions to user space*](https://lwn.net/Articles/756233/) on LWN.net.

Comment: oh.... well I was tried this before but it's problem is it is process based. can we use seccomp-bpf program system wide?? and another question, can I do this with pure lsm?? that's mean I block lsm and wait for user response. not in bpf, in pure lsm.